# visual studios 2013 template class non default constructor extern error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

So I'm having this error and I'm pulling my hair out.  I'm in Visual Studios 2013 and am getting this error:

> Error 1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall
>   testClass::testClass(int)" (??0?$testClass@H@@QAE@H@Z)
>   referenced in function _main  D:\Source Code\My Projects\test c++\test
>   c++ project\ErrorTesting\ErrorTesting\test.obj    ErrorTesting

file: testclass.h

```
template<typename t>
class testClass
{
public:
    testClass(t test);
};
```

file: testclass.cpp

```
#include "testclass.h"
template<typename t>
testClass<t>::testClass(t test)
{

}
```

file:test.cpp

```
#include "testclass.h"
int main()
{
    testClass<int> temp(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Now I don't know why I can't call a non-default constructor with a template type but it compiles just fine if I call a default constructor.

Please note this is an example of the code that causes the error not my main project that I'm working on.

Comment: Put the template definitions in the header file and look at the right: "Related" questions

Comment: instead of template <typename t> use template<class t>